# How to select every li element but not those in a span

Tags: html, css

A lot would say its a simple question but strangely i get stuck on it.
Have a look here : **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9zs62da/23/)**

What interest us is this part of the code :

```
<div class="customSelect">
  <ul>
    <li class="title not"> Top Villes de départ</li>
  <span class="topDes">
    <li id="test" value="PAR"> Paris</li>
    <li value="LYS"> Lyon</li>
    <li value="NTE"> Nantes</li>
  </span>
    <li class="separ not" value=""></li>
    <li class="title not" value="0">Toute les villes de départ</li>
  </ul>
</div>

.customSelect li:not(.topDes ){
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

I want to apply a `padding-left : 5px` to every `<li>` elements but not those between the `<span class=".topDes">` tag.

I tried `.customSelect:not(.topDes) li{...}` and other combinations but I dont see any changes.

What is the best way of doing that ?

Comment: You really shouldn't have `span` wrapped around `li`. It looks wrong (and probably is wrong).

Comment: Would: `ul .topDes li{ padding-left:20px !important;}` not help? where you can use any desired value

Comment: @alesc is correct, that's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is invalid, you can't have a `<span>` as a direct child of your `<ul>`. Instead use classes:

```css
li:not(.topDes) {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customSelect">
  <ul>
    <li class="title not"> Top Villes de départ</li>
    <li class="topDes" id="test" value="PAR"> Paris</li>
    <li class="topDes" value="LYS"> Lyon</li>
    <li class="topDes" value="NTE"> Nantes</li>
    <li class="separ not" value=""></li>
    <li class="title not" value="0">Toute les villes de départ</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also, value isn't a valid attribute for a list-item. Instead use the `data-*` attributes.

## edit

Rereading your question makes me wonder. Are you trying to make a sublist in your list? Then you might want to try this:

```html
<div class="customSelect">
  <ul>
    <li class="title not"> Top Villes de départ
      <ul>
        <li id="test" value="PAR"> Paris</li>
        <li value="LYS"> Lyon</li>
        <li value="NTE"> Nantes</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="separ not" value=""></li>
    <li class="title not" value="0">Toute les villes de départ</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nup not a sub list  just a list with specific class. You're first answer was good. Thank you :)

Link to the finish fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/h9zs62da/25/

Answer (score 0):

Use '>' in selector. It will take only elements on the next level and not deeper.

```
.customSelect ul > li {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

But better solution is just to create a class for elements that should have padding and not using spans to separate such elements.

Comment: Ho yeah very well think. I keep that in mind thank you !